# Do superconductors really have 0 resistance in reality?

Tags: electricity, electric-current, electrical-resistance

Do superconductors really have zero resistance in reality? If yes, then by ohm's law, I = V/R. I = V/zero. I = Infinity?

Comment: Yes, they really have 0 resistance. Note that the voltage drop across the superconductor is 0 as well.